# How to visit each url inside the sitemap using array?

Tags: arrays, cypress

I have a sitemap looks like this:

[image]

Then what I would like to do in cypress is to visit each link on the list and insert some test in every link.

Yes, I can just click on it, but my main problem is the list is constantly changing in number so clicking links is not an option.

What I am thinking is to get all the links and push them into an array and visit. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this if you want to visit all the links and then do some assertion inside the link

```js
var links = []
cy.get('a')
  .each(($ele) => {
    links.push($ele.attr('href'))
  })
  .then(() => {
    links.forEach((link) => {
      cy.visit(link)
      //Add some test here
      cy.get('selector').should('be.visible').and('have.text', text)
    })
  })
```

Or if you just want to check that the link returns 200 or not, you can do this:

```js
var links = []
cy.get('a')
  .each(($ele) => {
    links.push($ele.attr('href'))
  })
  .then(() => {
    links.forEach((link) => {
      cy.request(link, {failOnStatusCode: false}).then((response) => {
        expect(response.status).to.eq(200)
      })
    })
  })
```

Comment: Same as previous answer.

Comment: I beg to differ; the previous answer uses aliases, but I didn't. In the previous answer, there is no mention of `cy.visit`; in mine, there is. The previous answer uses an if condition to check the response status; I am using an `expect` assertion and so on.

Comment: For me this is the best way in my situation in testing in sitemap. Thanks bud for your help!

Answer (score 5):

Cannot really tell what your testing aim is, but here are two approaches that are pretty much text-book

**Test the link is valid**

```js
cy.get('li a')       
  .then($li => {
    return [...$li].map(el => el.href)
  })
  .as('hrefs')

cy.get('@hrefs')
  .then(hrefs =>

    hrefs.forEach(href => {
      cy.request({url: href, failOnStatusCode: false})
        .then(response => {
          if (response.statusCode !== 200) {
            // do what you want with bad link
          }
        })
    })
  })
```

**Test the link is clickable**

```js
cy.get('li').each($li => {
  cy.wrap($li).click()
    // do what you want with new page
    cy.go('back')
  })
```

Comment: Yes the code below what i i'm trying to find. But i'm getting an error says "failed because this element is detached from the DOM."

Comment: Well, is it "constantly changing"  between testing each link or is that list fixed for the duration of the test run?

Comment: The list is fixed for the duration of the test run and it only changes every week.

I also tried putting cy.waits but it only proceeds on the 1st link and get the same error afterwards

Comment: I recommend using `cy.request` to test the links. `cy.visit` will take a long time to process. Have updated the code.

Answer (score 3):

This variation of @Fody's answer worked for me

```js
const linkSelector = 'ul.sitemaplist li a'  // only links in the list

cy.get(linkSelector).each(($a, index) => {
  cy.get(linkSelector).eq(index).click()
  // do what you want with new page
  cy.go('back')
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Jason is correct, but (presuming the list doesn't change each time the page loads), you can try to query inside the `.each()` by index

```js
cy.get('li').each(($li, index) => {
  cy.get('li').eq(index).click()
  // do what you want with new page
  cy.go('back')
})
```

If that does not work, usually a recursive function will handle this scenario.